# WinApi: SetWindowLongPtr возвращает ошибку, но работает

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит:

Мне необходимо применить для моего Родительского окна в ходе срабатывания определенного условия в `WindProc` - стиль `WS_VSCROLL`, ну чтобы в какой то момент у окна появилась вертикальная полоса прокрутки.
Собственно, я вызываю функцию:

```
     SetLastError(1);   //MSDN рекомендует установить код перед вызовом SetWindowLongPtr
        LONG_PTR My_LONG_PTR = SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_VSCROLL);
        cout << GetLastError() << endl;//Код ошибки 87 - неверный параметр
```

Как видно при таком вызове - возникает ошибка 87 - неверный параметр.
Только стоит изменить `GWL_EXSTYLE` на `GWL_STYLE`, в этом случае, код ошибки установленный `SetLastError()` - не меняется, то есть `SetWindowLongPtr` - завершается успешно. Все хорошо и классно.

Но меня интересует другое, а именно, почему в первом случае, функция завершилась с ошибкой 87, но все равно применила указанный `WS_VSCROLL` стиль, то есть у окна появилась вертикальная полоса прокрутки.

Answer (score 2):

`SetWindowLong[Ptr]` не просто сеттер в некоторую область памяти, даже скорее "просто не сеттер", хоть и константы похоже на смещения. Она обрабатывает входящие значения, особенно `GWL_EXSTYLE` / `GWL_STYLE`

Окну приходят [`WM_STYLECHANGING`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-stylechanging)/`WM_STYLECHANGED`. В первом из них окно может исправить и установленные стили, и возвращаемое старое значение.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, в расширенном  стиле должны присутствовать определённые компоненты. Чтобы не разрушить стиль совсем, а только добавить нужное, делают так:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_VSCROLL | GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE));
```

Comment: MBo, Спасибо, но мой вопрос немного был в другом, а именно: почему в первом случае, функция завершилась с ошибкой 87, НО ВСЕ РАВНО ПРИМЕНИЛА указанный WS_VSCROLL стиль, то есть у окна появилась вертикальная полоса прокрутки.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, нужно внимательно сделать точно то, что написано в MSDN, а именно:

> by calling SetLastError with 0

Чистить старое состояние ошибки значением 0 (вы задаете 1)

> Function failure will be indicated by a return value of zero and a
> GetLastError result that is nonzero.

Ошибка возникает, когда функция вернула 0 и GetLastError вернула не 0, у сравнения возвращенного функцией значения с 0 нет

Comment: gbg, ноль ставить не обязательно, но я делал и с нулем, в итоге состояние GetLastError() так же меняется на 87, и My_LONG_PTR  ==0, то есть ОШИБКА. Но стиль все равно применяется, в этом и вопрос, почему ?

Comment: @Optimus1, не воспроизводится.

Comment: – ヒミコ , а что именно не воспроизводится ? SetWindowLongPtr - возвращает ошибку и стиль не применяется ?

Comment: @Optimus1, Именно, [код для теста](https://gist.github.com/dev-iCEY/7f3137c23c87a0c71e27f138bd2318ee), запускать с параметром `--extend`, не появится скролл, запустишь без параметра, будет скроллбар. И еще, добавляй @ перед именем, оповещание что бы приходило.

Comment: – ヒミコ, нашел у себя ошибку, хотя по мне это не совсем очевидная ошибка, у меня после SetWindowLongPtr() и вызывается функция SetScrollInfo(), в описании, которой говорится, что она устанавливает параметры для полосы прокрутки, но не устанавливает стиль для окна, то есть теоретически, если стиль WS_VSCROLL к окну не установлен, то и SetScrollInfo() - не должна была работать, как я думал. Если я ее у себя закомментирую, то да, тоже полоса прокрутки не появляется.

Comment: @Optimus1 и как бы мы это нашли, если выложенный вами код не совпадает с тем, который у вас плохо работает?

Comment: gbg, согласен полностью мой косяк. Но я думал, что SetScrollInfo() - не должен применять к окну стили, поэтому и не привел его в описании, а должен был. Прошу прощения.